# How to reach an object value (Map-Areas)

Tags: javascript

I have created an object map area which dynamically changes the map areas with Pictures. Now I have a function where you should get redirected to another map area. I have a confirm window when you press on a certain area. After you press yes or no it should redirect you to the specific map. But how?

```
// Object Map-Area
var _images = {
 homepage: {  
    path: 'homepage.jpg',    
    areas: [{                 
        coords: '45,143,106,158',   
        text: 'Homepage',        
        clickHandler: doSomething
    }]
  },
}
  //DOM-Elements
 image.areas.forEach(function(area) {

    var areaElem = document.createElement('AREA');
    areaElem.coords = area.coords;
    areaElem.setAttribute('link', area.goto);
    areaElem.setAttribute("title", area.text);
    areaElem.setAttribute("shape", "rect");
   //click handler and click listener
    areaElem.addEventListener('click', onArea_click);
    areaElem.addEventListener('click', area.clickHandler);
    _map.appendChild(areaElem);     
      })
}

function onArea_click(domEvent) {    
  //update cuurent imageid with current link
  _currentImageId = domEvent.target.getAttribute('link');  

  refreshImage();
}
function doSomething(e){
var areaClicked= e.target;

  var r = confirm("Data will get lost!");
  if (r == true) {
      // I know I need something like in the function onArea_click
      //Now how can I redirect to  map homepage ?
  } else {
     //or to a different one?    
 }
// There is missing code but it's not important for what I need now because then the code will get sooo long.
```

**EDIT:**   Here the whole refreshImage function.

```
function refreshImage() { 

  var image = _images[_currentImageId];   
  _image.src = image.path;

  _map.innerHTML = ""; 
  image.areas.forEach(function(area) {

    var areaElem = document.createElement('AREA');
    areaElem.coords = area.coords;
    areaElem.setAttribute('link', area.goto);
    areaElem.setAttribute("title", area.text);
    areaElem.setAttribute("shape", "rect");

    areaElem.addEventListener('click', onArea_click);
    areaElem.addEventListener('click', area.clickHandler);
    _map.appendChild(areaElem);  

  })
}
```

Comment: When you say "redirect", do you mean you just want to change it out for a different image and areamap?

Comment: Yes, I want to change the areamap and the image

Comment: Presumably you've got a `refreshImage()` function somewhere that changes the image and area map--so you would probably use that. But you're asking the question, so maybe that part doesn't work or something. But then it's not in the code, etc. etc... It's pretty hard to figure out what part you need done. We only see separate parts of the code but not how it all ties together. It's good that you didn't overload us with the whole thing, we need to see the specific parts involved in what you're trying to do.

Comment: I attched the whole refreshImage function

Comment: Ah, that makes more sense. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
function doSomething(e) {
  var areaClicked= e.target;

  var r = confirm("Data will get lost!");
  if (r == true) {
      _currentImageId = e.target.getAttribute('link'); // or "homepage"
      refreshImage();
  } else {
     // do nothing; they don't want to lose any data
  }
}
```

Comment: You already had it in your onclick handler. Maybe this didn't work, or I'm misunderstanding something?

Comment: Hmm, doesn't work though. Nothing happens, no errors

Comment: Are you actually running `doSomething` somewhere?

Comment: Yes , you can see it in the object _Images. There is a clickHandler. Only the confirm window pops up, but nothing happens when I click on Yes

Comment: And if you `console.log` something in `doSomething`, does it show that it's being run when you click something? Why is it that you've got 2 events hooked in to the area?

Comment: I can alert something when I click on yes so it should work. What do you mean 2 events hooked ?

Comment: areaElem.addEventListener('click', onArea_click);
    areaElem.addEventListener('click', area.clickHandler);

Comment: Oh, I have areas with onclick defined. They go to a different areamap. I just used clickHandler to avoid confusion.

Comment: So if the user cancels the confirm box, you want to cancel the normal click (which changes the image to the new one anyway)? And if they confirm (hit OK) then you want to let the normal click happen (which changes the image)?

Comment: Sorry. I explained myself bad. When you click on No nothing happens and on Yes it should go to homepage so it should go to the areamap homepage where also the picture is defined

Comment: Just to check: confirm -> yes (ok) -> move to the picture/areamap linked to by the areamap. confirm -> no (cancel) -> nothing happens.

Comment: Exactly, Yes -> go to new map/Picture and No -> nothing , so the No part is easy ^^

Comment: And you can get an alert out of `doSomething` but not a confirm?

Comment: The confirm window appears, but when I click on Yes nothing happens, when I put an alert inside if (r == true) {} then I get my alert.

Comment: Okay. Are you appending the image in `refreshImage` or unhiding it or something? Put an alert in that function and see what happens.

Comment: No. In the actual `refreshImage` function, at the top. We need to see if it's being called after you click.

I tell you what, if you could make a jsfiddle with all the basic parts in it, that would really help me figure out what's going on.

Comment: In the fiddle, you were getting the "edit" attribute in `doSomething` which wasn't there. Also, there's no goto on the homepage area. I've fixed it in the fiddle, but there's a load of alerts and whatever. https://jsfiddle.net/n35hyk3h/4/

Comment: Hmm, it works kinda, but those alerts are not that what Im looking for , also the confirm window appears after you clicked on the specific area xD

Comment: Hey, man. You know you can delete or comment out those alerts, right? I'm not sure what you mean about the confirm box--is there still a problem with it?

Comment: I know, the confirm window appears after you clicked the area so it's not correct and after clicking yes nothing happens so .....

Comment: Are you sure you're look at the right fiddle? https://jsfiddle.net/n35hyk3h/7/        I thought the idea was the confirm appears when you click on the area, and then if you click OK (yes) the picture changes. That's what your code seemed to be aiming for. Was that not right?

Comment: No It should be exactly the opposite ^^ After the confirm  window it should go to the new area map.  I commented  _currentImageId = e.target.getAttribute('link');   refreshImage(); out and it's still working so we can say it's doing nothing right now, like before. You just added goto when you click on the area so it's not what I'm looking for.

Comment: Okay, give me a flow chart of what you want to happen. Like click -> confirm -> yes -> change image/area.

Comment: Yes. It's simple. Click on area -> confirm window pops up -> click yes and get redirected to new pictures/area or press no and stay in current area/picture .

Comment: Is there a reason you've got two separate listeners on the same thing?

Comment: Noo, just for myself so I don't get confusioned

Comment: Okay, well it's causing all sorts of headaches, I'm afraid. I've commented out that area_onClick thing and now it works as expected. https://jsfiddle.net/n35hyk3h/17/ Is that right?

Comment: But when you commeted it out I won't using my function anymore , also all other things won't work , I can't click any other areas more

Comment: So is this just a one-off effect, with the confirm box? Are there other areas that need this same effect? Are there other areas that need a different extra effect on top of just changing the image?

Comment: Well there are other areas too, I just gave you two areas to test it. No they should have all the same effect.

Comment: Okay. I've incorporated that login into the existing area_onClick. In the config for an area that needs confirmation, just add the property "confirm" with the value `true`. I commented out the doSomething stuff, and added the area_onClick back in. https://jsfiddle.net/n35hyk3h/20/

Comment: Thank you for you effort, but now I can't click normal areas without alert windows ^^ Wait, ist working now ^^

Comment: Another question, what if I want to have more functions doing the same thing but the confirmation text is different ? For example If have another area, by clicking it's showing me a different text but the output is the same, so it's going to the same area/picture.

Comment: Do you want it templated, so it says "You're trying to go to _name_of_image_. Doing so would lose data!" Or a custom message for each area?

Comment: (By the way, I'm pretty much coding this whole thing myself at this point. I'm meant to be answering a question or figuring out a problem, not develop an app _for_ you.)

Comment: Custom message, because I have two more areas where a different message should appear. Hehe ^^ I'm sorry, thank you for your work =).

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/n35hyk3h/24/ I think that's where I'm going to stop. Honestly, this isn't really fair--this is not what this forum is for.

Comment: Thank you for your work again. It's because I never really worked that much with object so I didn't know how to write it correctly. Also a short question, what if i want to copy an already existing area map like homepage inside edit to make the code shorter. Do I need setters and getters ?

Comment: You could set it after the main config is all set up. Something like `_images.edit.areas=_images.homepage.areas`. Next time you post a question, be very specific about what you're trying to find out, or what the problem is. And once that's covered, give them the answer and move on; don't take advantage of their kind help. And in the meantime I'd recommend you look at some tutorials for [how to use objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects).

Comment: Really, thank you very much =) I will read it . Have a nice day ^-^